# Google API Console - Orange Exclamation Point

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-api-console

I created a project in the Google apis Console that enables the Google Maps API V3 and Places API Services. I have provided billing information and verified my email.

In the API Access tab, I have generated an API Key but an orange exclamation point is shown on the tab. (The Overview tab indicates that both APIs have no known issues).

When I try a sample search within Chrome (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&sensor=false&key=MyKEY) "Access Denied is returned in the Google Places status XML.

I assume the Access denied message has something to do with the orange exclamation point,  but I have searched and searched for the meaning of this exclamation point to no avail.

Any insights as to the meaning of the exclamation point or reason for the Access Denied message are much appreciated.

**EDIT**
I am now able to retrieve XML with status=OK, but the orange exclamation point remains; I still would like to know what it means.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I had an API key and went through the process of filling out the billing tab to make the orange exclamation mark disappear. To test the API I found it more effective to take the one supplied in simple API box and replace it with the one [here](http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_first)

I found that I could test API keys in this way even if the exclamation mark was shown as I believe this only relates to billable keys.